# Class 'Laracon21\Colorcodeconverter\ColorcodeconverterServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to run a Laravel project but I am getting the following error:

```
$ php artisan config:cache

In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
                                                                                    
  Class 'Laracon21\Colorcodeconverter\ColorcodeconverterServiceProvider' not found
```

I tried `composer require laracon21/colorcodeconverter` to add `laracon21`, it's added in the vendor folder successfully but the composer does not update perfectly, showing:

```
Problem 1
     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.30
     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.29
     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.28
     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.27
       .
       .
       .
     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.0
     - laracon21/colorcodeconverter 1.1 requires illuminate/support ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[7.x-dev], illuminate/support[7.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.15.0, v7.16.0, v7.16.1, v7.17.0, v7.17.1, v7.17.2, v7.18.0, v7.19.0, v7.19.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.20.0, v7.21.0, v7.22.0, v7.22.1, v7.22.2, v7.22.3, v7.22.4, v7.23.0, v7.23.1, v7.23.2, v7.24.0, v7.25.0, v7.26.0, v7.26.1, v7.27.0, v7.28.0, v7.28.1, v7.28.2, v7.28.3, v7.28.4, v7.29.0, v7.29.1, v7.29.2, v7.29.3, v7.3.0, v7.30.0, v7.30.1, v7.30.2, v7.30.3, v7.30.4, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
     - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[7.x-dev, 6.x-dev].
     - don't install illuminate/support 7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
     - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.0|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
     - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.1|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
     - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.2|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
```

And here is my `composer.json`:

```js
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "anandsiddharth/laravel-paytm-wallet": "^1.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "gabrielbull/ups-api": "^0.8.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.5",
        "instamojo/instamojo-php": "^0.4.0",
        "laracasts/flash": "^3.0",
        "laracon21/colorcodeconverter": "^1.1",
        "laravel/framework": "6.*",
        "laravel/passport": "^7.3",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "mehedi-iitdu/core-component-repository": "dev-master",
        "mehedi-iitdu/laravel-paystack": "dev-master",
        "mehedi-iitdu/paypal": "dev-master",
        "nexmo/laravel": "^2.2",
        "razorpay/razorpay": "2.0.0",
        "spatie/laravel-image-optimizer": "^1.3",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^6.29",
        "twilio/sdk": "^6.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": ["app/Http/Helpers.php"]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
                "laravel/dusk"
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Please help me. how can I solve this?

Comment: this package requires a higher version of the Laravel framework

Answer (score 2):

Don't you see it requires `laravel: ^7.0.0` ? You are trying to use `laravel: ^6.x`...

The error says it clearly: `illuminate/support ^7.0`, `don't install laravel/framework v6.0.0`.

So, you must change it to `7.x`.